# How to attribute images in questions and answers?

Tags: discussion, images, copyright, attribution

When a question uses an image without attribution, and the source is not germane to the question or answer except insofar as proper attribution, what is the best way to attribute the image? In an edit to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46208020/plotting-two-line-plots-of-different-index-lengths-with-disconnects-where-there), I named the author of the book containing the unattributed image and made the name "Joe Kuan" link to a page selling the book containing the image. Does this attribution suffice?

Comment: Reviewing my question after 8th upvote. As an academic, the citation to the book would be better. As a potential buyer, a buy-here link is convenient, maybe is way to say thank you to the author. Stack Overflow is a for profit (acquired at $1.8 billion in 2021, business model described at https://productmint.com/how-does-stack-overflow-make-money). I checked because if it had been a nonprofit, open-source, academic-knowledge-aggregating model, commercial is iffy. My use of URL to buy-here link was just for my own convenience as the first place I found the image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `<sub></sub>`html tag to edit an attribution below the image.

Sample:

```
[![graph][1]][1]  
<sub>This graph from https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/line-area-and-scatter-charts originally created by Jon Kuan</sub>
```

[image: graph]
<sub>This graph from https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/line-area-and-scatter-charts originally created by Jon Kuan</sub>

Sample post can be found [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356868/4826457) by @CodyGray.